# Image not getting displayed in JSP - AWS environment only

Tags: jsp, nginx

I have a JSP page where I display an image. While loading JSP page, it loads the image(as visible in Network tab) but the image is not displayed in the popup opened(JSP page)

JSP page code as per Network trace

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Graph</title>
<link href="/portal/image/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/js/javaScriptFunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload='setWindowWidthHeight("false");'>   
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=1017 height=723 style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;background-image:url(/portal/processimage?workFlowId=1342)">
<tr><td>
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Same thing gets displayed in browser if I hit the image URL directly. Also. this flow works perfectly fine in another local environment.

Is there anything specific that I might be missing related to configuration or what might be other possible reasons for this?

WebServer used is nginx

WebPage: [image]

Image in Network trace:  [image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot from the browsers network panel as well as from the browsers console output?

Comment: Thanks @TimoStark. I have added the screenshots

Comment: Can you show me the header tab content for the image? That would be great!